# Is There a Better Way of Checking Nil or Length == 0 of a String in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a better way than the following to check to see if a string is nil OR has a length of 0 in Ruby?

```ruby
if !my_string || my_string.length == 0
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

In C# there's the handy

```csharp
string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)
```

Anything similar to that in Ruby?

Comment: It's redundant to have an if-statement like this: "if (condition) then true else false". The condition itself has the same truthiness as the if-statement.

Comment: `my_string || my_string.length == 0` will raise a `NoMethodError` if `my_string` is nil. I think you meant: `my_string.nil? || my_string.length == 0`

Comment: Should it be `!my_string || my_string.length == 0`

Answer (score 234, accepted):

When I'm not worried about performance, I'll often use this:

```
if my_string.to_s == ''
  # It's nil or empty
end
```

There are various variations, of course...

```
if my_string.to_s.strip.length == 0
  # It's nil, empty, or just whitespace
end
```

Comment: The variation using `strip` can be quite inefficient.

Comment: another interesting way is my_string.to_s.empty?

Comment: For most people the first option will be completely acceptable, and reads well.

Answer (score 73):

If you are willing to require ActiveSupport you can just use the `#blank?` method, which is defined for both NilClass and String.

Comment: Note that a String containing only whitespace is still considered blank. So " ".blank? is true.

Comment: Also, boolean false, {}, and [] are considered blank. I.e. {}.blank?, [].blank?, false.blank? all evaluate to true.

Answer (score 67):

I like to do this as follows (in a non Rails/ActiveSupport environment):

```
variable.to_s.empty?
```

this works because:

```
nil.to_s == ""
"".to_s == ""
```

Comment: A good explanation why `string.to_s.empty?` works for both `nil` and `""`.

Answer (score 32):

An alternative to jcoby's proposal would be:

```
class NilClass
  def nil_or_empty?
    true
  end
end

class String
  def nil_or_empty?
    empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: But .. but .. The ruby core library already implements this. nil.to_s => "", so you can say thing.to_s == ""

Comment: @DigitalRoss This avoids the string conversion which may or may not be a slight performance issue.

Answer (score 31):

As it was said here before Rails (ActiveSupport) have a handy [blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#M000155) method and it is implemented like this:

```
class Object
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end
end
```

Pretty easy to add to any ruby-based project.

The beauty of this solution is that it works auto-magicaly not only for Strings but also for Arrays and other types.

Answer (score 15):

variable.blank? will do it.
It returns true if the string is empty or if the string is nil.

Comment: Actually, this is a rails only extension, not pure ruby. But if you are using rails it is very handy!

Answer (score 13):

`nil?` can be omitted in boolean contexts. Generally, you can use this to replicate the C# code:

```
return my_string.nil? || my_string.empty?
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, beware of that method:

As [Jesse Ezel](http://weblogs.asp.net/jezell/archive/2003/04/10/5280.aspx) says:

> [Brad Abrams](http://blogs.gotdotnet.com/brada/commentview.aspx/ed33b21f-39a1-4eba-8c62-5e578d6d989a)
>
> > "The method might seem convenient, but most of the time I have found that this situation arises from trying to cover up deeper bugs.
>
> Your code should stick to a particular protocol on the use of strings, and you should understand the use of the protocol in library code and in the code you are working with.
>
> The NullOrEmpty protocol is typically a quick fix (so the real problem is still somewhere else, and you got two protocols in use) or it is a lack of expertise in a particular protocol when implementing new code (and again, you should really know what your return values are)."

And if you patch String class... be sure [NilClass has not been patch either](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/poignant-stiffs/2004-May/000077.html)!

```
class NilClass
    def empty?; true; end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Every class has a `nil?` method:

```
if a_variable.nil?
    # the variable has a nil value
end
```

And strings have the `empty?` method:

```
if a_string.empty?
    # the string is empty
}
```

Remember that a string does *not* equal `nil` when it is empty, so use the `empty?` method to check if a string is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to convert nil to an empty result on the fly:

`(my_string||'').empty?`

Answer (score 2):

Konrad Rudolph has the right answer.

If it really bugs you, monkey patch the String class or add it to a class/module of your choice.  It's really not a good practice to monkey patch core objects unless you have a really compelling reason though.

```
class String
  def self.nilorempty?(string)
    string.nil? || string.empty?
  end
end
```

Then you can do `String.nilorempty? mystring`

Answer (score 2):

### Check for Empty Strings in Plain Ruby While Avoiding NameError Exceptions

There are some good answers here, but you don't need ActiveSupport or monkey-patching to address the common use case here. For example:

```
my_string.to_s.empty? if defined? my_string
```

This will "do the right thing" if *my_string* is nil or an empty string, but will not raise a [NameError exception](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/NameError.html) if *my_string* is not defined. This is generally preferable to the more contrived:

```
my_string.to_s.empty? rescue NameError
```

or its more verbose ilk, because exceptions should really be saved for things you *don't* expect to happen. In this case, while it might be a common error, an undefined variable isn't really an exceptional circumstance, so it should be handled accordingly.

Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using rails, you can use `#present?`

```
require 'rails'

nil.present?  # ==> false (Works on nil)
''.present?    # ==> false (Works on strings)
'  '.present?  # ==> false (Works on blank strings)
[].present?    # ==> false(Works on arrays)
false.present? # ==> false (Works on boolean)
```

So, conversely to check for nil or zero length use `!present?`

```
!(nil.present?)  # ==> true
!(''.present?)    # ==> true
!('  '.present?)  # ==> true
!([].present?)    # ==> true
!(false.present?) # ==> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Refinements?

```
module Nothingness
  refine String do
    alias_method :nothing?, :empty?
  end

  refine NilClass do
    alias_method :nothing?, :nil?
  end
end

using Nothingness

return my_string.nothing?
```

Answer (score 0):

For code golfers:

```ruby
if my_string=~/./
  p 'non-empty string'
else
  p 'nil or empty string'
end
```

Or if you're not a golfer (requires ruby 2.3 or later):

```ruby
if my_string&.size&.positive?
  # nonzero? also works
  p 'non-empty string'
else
  p 'nil or empty string'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can try `#blank?`.

Warning: it will give you positives when string consists of spaces:

```
nil.blank? # ==> true
''.blank? # ==> true
'  '.blank? # ==> true
'false'.blank? # ==> false
```

Just wanted to point it out. Maybe it suits your needs

UPD. why am i getting old questions in my feed?
Sorry for necroposting.