# HTML form empty textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I have a textfield in a form with `name="test"`. When I enter a value in, my params hash contains that value:

```
 params[:test] => "value"
```

However, if I don't enter a value in,  my params hash contains an empty string:

```
 params[:test] => ""
```

My question is, how do I tell if the user manually entered an empty string or simply ignored/did not touch the field at all?

**UPDATE**
Ok, let me explain the real issue, maybe I am not exapling myself well. I have bunch of search fields on a page, and I need to search based on them. This is what I am doing right now:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:artist_name] = s_artist_name if s_artist_name && !s_artist_name.empty?
conditions[:city] = s_city if s_city && !s_city.empty?
```

I have to first check if it's `nil`, and then check if it's `emtpty?` . This doesn't look good to me, I don't know...it's too much work for such a simple task. I must be missing something . Or is this how it's done? 
I check for `nil` because if I call:

```
xyz.com/test
```

params will be nil.

If I press button on `test` page without entering anything in the fields, params will be populated but with empty string. 
So then I check for empty string as well.

Comment: how can you enter an empty string manually?

Comment: @nurettin click on it and not enter anything?

Comment: @\0xSina sounds like you want to catch a client-side event

Comment: Write that text area filed with different name. So obviously the object won't take into its `params` until you apply for. Try as `text_area_tag 'your_interested_name'` .

Comment: Are you guys saying that if my params[:value] = "", then I should treat it as nil? i.e. it was never touched?

Comment: @nurettin I updated my questions with more info on what my problem is.

Comment: @VenkatK I updated my questions with more info on what my problem is.

Comment: check for blank? instead of nill and empty?

Comment: @OxSina did you ever fix this issue? I have similar problem where optional fields are passed as ("") empty string on the backend, which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Checking

**value.present?** checks for both nil & empty and returns true if value is not nil and not empty.
**value.blank?** checks for both nil & empty and returns true if value is nil or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post will help you 
[Is There a Better Way of Checking Nil or Length == 0 of a String in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247948/is-there-a-better-way-of-checking-nil-or-length-0-of-a-string-in-ruby)

Got many ways that people use to check for empty values, hope this helps.