# Rails Model method check if field nil, if so return empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model class I have a method:

```
def full_address
    address_lines = [self.address1,self.address2,self.address3].reject!(&:empty?).join(',')
    fulladdress = address_lines + ", " + self.city + ', ' + self.state  + ', ' + self.zipcode
    return fulladdress 
end
```

This is just an easy way to return all the address fields to view them quickly.

This returns `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass`when its empty.  How can I change the method to work if all address1, address2, address3 are empty?

I guess I'm looking for a function like:

```
ReturnBlankIfNilElseValue(self.address1)
```

Anything like that exist?

```
def full_address
    address_lines = [self.address1.to_s,self.address2.to_s,self.address3.to_s].reject!(&:empty?).join(',')
    fulladdress = address_lines + ", " + self.city + ', ' + self.state  + ', ' + self.zipcode
    return fulladdress 
end
```

This variation returns `no implicit conversion of nil into String` which is odd because in rails console i can type `nil.to_s` and get an empty string.

I don't really want to check if each field is nil and then add to the array, i'd prefer a function that just returned empty string if it is nil.

**Sorry the nil.to_s does work its the 2nd line that needed one as well.  Its working now will get rid of this.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is There a Better Way of Checking Nil or Length == 0 of a String in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247948/is-there-a-better-way-of-checking-nil-or-length-0-of-a-string-in-ruby)

Comment: I don't believe to be a duplicate. i want to return blank if nil not check if its nil.

Comment: You have to check for nil, in order to return blank. How else would you do it?

Comment: `nil.to_s` is an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, although this might not be what you wanted, simply remove any `nil` objects from the address Array using [the `#compact` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact), so that `#empty?` will work...:

```
def full_address
    [self.address1, self.address2, self.address3,
        self.city, self.state, self.zipcode].compact.reject!(&:empty?).join(', ')
end
```

You should be aware that this WILL return a partial address if SOME of the fields exist.

I would probably void any fault addresses (in this example I require just the first address line and the city fields):

```
def full_address
    return "" unless self.address1 && self.city && !self.address1.empty? && !self.city.empty? 
    [self.address1, self.address2, self.address3,
        self.city, self.state, self.zipcode].compact.reject!(&:empty?).join(', ')
end
```

Disregarding the few edits I made to the code, I would probably go with @Joseph's `#present?` together with the validation, since you're using Rails:

```
def full_address
    return "" unless self.address1 && self.city && self.address1.present? && self.city.present? 
    [self.address1, self.address2, self.address3,
        self.city, self.state, self.zipcode].reject!(&:present?).join(', ')
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is a much for succinct solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use `present?` to check for nil without throwing an error (it returns false for nil and for empty string or a string with just spaces in it).

So, instead of using `reject` and `empty?`, you can use `select` and `present?`.

```
    address_lines = [self.address1,self.address2,self.address3].select(&:present?).join(',')
```

This won't return an empty string for blank or nil addresses -- it will just leave them out of address_lines.

Note `present?` is the opposite of `blank?` suggested by chad_. I think either one will help you get the result you need.

Decent summary on this blog: http://railsless.blogspot.com/2011/08/difference-between-nil-empty-blank.html

Answer (score 1):

In rails, you can check `foo.blank?` and it will check `nil? || empty`

Comment: It is declared by [Object#blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F), so it works on anything.

Also, blank? is a one liner that just checks if the object responds to empty? and calls that if it is there, otherwise it it returns true unless self is present.  Basically the point is to call it on nil to find out if it's nil...