# How to check if controller action variable is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried this in my views

```
<% if @post.url == nil %>
<h1>File not found!</h1>
<% end %>
```

in post controller I have

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

how to check if `@post.url` is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just go with

```
if @post.url.nil?
```

which returns `true` when `@post.url` is `nil` but `false` when `@post.url` is an empty string.

Alternatively, you can use

```
if @post.url.blank?
```

which returns `true` in both cases when `@post.url` is `nil` or an empty string.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base#find` raises an exception if the record cannot be found, does not it?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Afaik understand the question the page exists, but `page.url` might be blank. I am not sure how `ActiveRecord::Base#find` raising an exception might help in this case.

Comment: I agree, there is a lack of understanding what problem OP actually experiences, but If the page exists, `<% if @post.url == nil %>` would work. `blank?` might be the solution then, yes.

Comment: "empty string" according to `String` is `""` but a `blank?` string is an `empty?` `String` or purely whitespace `"   "` or `"\r\n\t"` using `empty? || (/\A[[:space:]]*\z/ === self)` (with some omitted error handling)

Answer (score 0):

The following answer to a similar question seems to be what you are after:

```
if my_string.to_s.empty?
  # It's nil or empty
end
```

see: [Is There a Better Way of Checking Nil or Length == 0 of a String in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247948/is-there-a-better-way-of-checking-nil-or-length-0-of-a-string-in-ruby)

If you need something more sophisticated than checking for nil or empty then you might want a URL validation method.